# Camel service call giving 400 error

Tags: apache-camel, httprequest

I am using Camel serviceCall to call my eureka VIP. The host and port are resolved as expected. But the response is 400 and an error is thrown. My serviceCall looks like something below:

```
    from("direct:servicecall")
    .setBody().constant(null)
    .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant(HttpMethods.GET))
    .serviceCall().name("eureka_vip_name")
    .expression()
    .simple("http4:${header.CamelServiceCallServiceHost}:${header.CamelServiceCallServicePort}"
        + "service call path and parameters")
    .end()
```

Adding the error logs:

> org.apache.camel.http.common.HttpOperationFailedException: HTTP operation failed invoking http://172.31.20.241:8080/<------url path and parameteres------> with statusCode: 400
>       at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.populateHttpOperationFailedException(HttpProducer.java:312) ~[camel-http4-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.component.http4.HttpProducer.process(HttpProducer.java:207) ~[camel-http4-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.util.AsyncProcessorConverterHelper$ProcessorToAsyncProcessorBridge.process(AsyncProcessorConverterHelper.java:61) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor$1.doInAsyncProducer(SendDynamicProcessor.java:132) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.ProducerCache.doInAsyncProducer(ProducerCache.java:445) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.SendDynamicProcessor.process(SendDynamicProcessor.java:127) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.cloud.DefaultServiceCallProcessor.execute(DefaultServiceCallProcessor.java:184) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.cloud.DefaultServiceCallProcessor.lambda$process$0(DefaultServiceCallProcessor.java:164) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.spring.cloud.CamelSpringCloudServiceLoadBalancer.lambda$process$0(CamelSpringCloudServiceLoadBalancer.java:66) ~[camel-spring-cloud-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:98) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.springframework.cloud.netflix.ribbon.RibbonLoadBalancerClient.execute(RibbonLoadBalancerClient.java:80) ~[spring-cloud-netflix-core-1.3.4.RELEASE.jar!/:1.3.4.RELEASE]
>       at org.apache.camel.spring.cloud.CamelSpringCloudServiceLoadBalancer.process(CamelSpringCloudServiceLoadBalancer.java:66) ~[camel-spring-cloud-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.impl.cloud.DefaultServiceCallProcessor.process(DefaultServiceCallProcessor.java:164) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.management.InstrumentationProcessor.process(InstrumentationProcessor.java:76) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler$AsyncRedeliveryTask.call(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:203) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
>       at org.apache.camel.processor.RedeliveryErrorHandler$AsyncRedeliveryTask.call(RedeliveryErrorHandler.java:171) ~[camel-core-2.20.1.jar!/:2.20.1]
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293) ~[?:1.8.0_161]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149) [?:1.8.0_161]
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624) [?:1.8.0_161]
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) [?:1.8.0_161]

I tried hitting the same url using from postMan (chrome extension): When hitting from postMan, i used the ec2 instance DNS name as host and it gives me the expected response ie, 200 OK with the expected body as result.

Comment: Well 400 means bad request. So compare your request to the one sent by Postman see what the difference is.

Comment: Did that. The requests is fine!

Comment: Well obviously something doesn't match since you are getting that error.

Answer (score 0):

Trying to answer tho this question event if it was written ages ago.

I've encountered the same problem and I've noticed that **this is due to some extra headers that were set in parent/previous routes**.

For example if you set in a parent route a header that is too long or in a different format (i.e. byte[]) this header is also sent to the http request and this produces the Http 400 error code.

I've solved by removing all headers by using **.removeHeaders("*")** before performing the http request:

```
 from("direct:myHttpRoute")
        .removeHeaders("*", "PrefixToKeepSomeHeaders*") // clean headers         
        .setHeader(Exchange.HTTP_METHOD, constant("GET"))
        .setHeader(Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE, constant("application/json"))
        .setBody().constant(null) // clean body
        .to("https://mypath.com")
        .log("Response: ${body}");
```

I hope this could be useful to someone else!